# Sugarcrm - Send only checked Queued Campaign emails

Tags: sugarcrm

In Email Queue, when I send queued campaign emails all emails are sent. I want it to send only the emails which are checked(selected checkboxes). Does any one know the way to do the same. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behavior, to modify it you'd check in `/modules/EmailMan` and ideally copy code/customization to the custom directory to try to stay as upgrade-safe as possible. Really, though, my experience with Campaign and Email customization is that there is heavy copy-paste from core files which are technically upgrade-safe but may not be upgrade-aware later on.

Also, the number of outgoing emails in a single blast can be controlled with Campaign Email Settings :

```
index.php?module=EmailMan&action=campaignconfig
```

On a more basic level though, why would you queue emails you don't want to send?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I'll try it for sure.

Comment: Hello Matthew, do you know which function is for sending queued campaign emails. I couldn't find it.

Comment: It's actually not a specific function, look in /modules/EmailMan/EmailManDelivery.php. SugarCRM has gone away from this method of file-based "actions" but if you watch the Email Queue POSTs, you'll see that it goes to index.php?module=EmailMan&action=EmailManDelivery which calls this file directly for execution. Same is true in the Scheduler, in /modules/Scheduler/_AddJobsHere.php the function runMassEmailCampaign() just calls EmailManDelivery in a require_once statement, not in an OO way.